# What is this line and how to remove it

Tags: ida, x86, static-analysis

[image]

I tried to unpack packed_dll, when the unpack stage done, i dumped unpacked_dll out and start to reverse. I pretty sure this is continuously function of that dll but this line show up. So what is this line and can i remove it for my static reverse stage ?
Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

The dashed line is added by IDA to denote code flow boundaries. For example, you can see another one after the unconditional `jmp`, and there should be one after each `retn` instruction. In graph view they correspond to the end of function graph nodes.

The most probable cause for the one after call is that the called function has been detected as *non-returning*.

You can go inside the call and see if "Attributes: noreturn" is printed in the function header. If the function does, in fact, return, you can clear the flag by editing the function properties (<kbd>Alt-P</kbd>).